# How to get emacs to load ess

Tags: emacs, ess

I installed emacs 26 via flatpak and ess using sudo apt-get.

Currently my ess exists at `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/elpa-src/ess-17.11` and I put in my .emacs file 
`(load "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/elpa-src/ess-17.11/")`. When I run emacs, I get the following warning:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/home/yannik/.emacs’:

File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/elpa-src/ess-17.11/
```

However, this directory clearly exists. How do I get emacs to detect ess? I've tried everything, `'(require ess-site)` didn't work either.

Comment: is there a reason you're not using the package manager, eg. `package-install`? `load` loads a file, use `C-h f load` to read its documentation. You want to add that directory to your load-path, eg. `(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/..../")`, but if you use the package manager that will all be handled for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `load` loads a single Emacs Lisp file. What you want to do here is make an entire directory accessible, which you'd do by adding it to the load path:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/elpa-src/ess-17.11/")
```

After that, you should find that `(require 'ess-site)` works - it will find the `ess-site` module in that directory.

---

That said, you might find it easier to install ESS using Emacs' package manager.  Follow the [instructions for activating the MELPA package archive](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started), and then type `M-x list-packages` and install `ess` from the list.  Emacs will download the package, copy it to `~/.emacs.d/elpa`, and arrange to load it.